# DD.close() NameError: global name 'DD' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

pyqt4, after successful login my login window close and next window open. i.e good but if i want close next window and go to login window the error shown

here is my code

Login.py

```
import DD

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from LoginError import LoginError

import os

class Ui_Login(object):

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # type: (close) -> object
        QtGui.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
        self.saveLayout()


    def loginCheck(self):

        username = self.lineEdit_adminusername.text()
        password = self.lineEdit_adminpassword.text()
        for line in open("password.txt", "r").readlines():  # Read the lines
            # str = in.readlines();
            # str1 = in.readlines();
            loginCheck_info = line.split()  # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
            # if username == str and password == str1:
            if username == loginCheck_info[0] and password == loginCheck_info[1]:
                print("Correct credentials!")
                try:
                    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
                    self.ui = DD.Ui_DD()
                    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
                    self.window.show()
                    Login.close()
                    return True
                except LoginError:
                    sys.exit()
                sys.exit(app.exec_())


            else:
                print "Incorrect credentials!!!"
                widget = QWidget()
                message = QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(widget, "Warning", "Please enter valid username and password")
                return False
                # print("Incorrect credentials.")
                # return False
            line.close()

    def reboot(self, event):
        widget = QWidget()
        message = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(widget, "Reboot", "Do you really want to Reboot?",
                                             QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if message == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print "Rebooting..........."
            os.system("reboot")

        else:
            print "Continue"
            global true;
            true = 1;

    def shutdown(self, event):
        widget = QWidget()
        message = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(widget, "Shutdown", "Do you really want to Shutdown?",
                                             QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if message == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print "Going to shutting down..........."
            os.system("poweroff")

        else:
            print "Continue"
            global true;
            true = 1;

        self.btn_adminlogin = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_adminlogin.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_adminlogin"))
        self.btn_adminlogin.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_adminlogin, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

DD.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import Login

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import os

import time

class Ui_DD(object):

    def Start(self):
        global true;
        true = 1;
        print "Start"
        widget = QWidget()
        message = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(widget, "Welcome", "Data Transfer Start")
        while true == 1:
            path = "/home/greensystem/PycharmProjects/data/"
            itemsTextList = 0
            for f in os.listdir(path):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
                    itemsTextList += 1

            print "Total number of files in: " + path + " -", itemsTextList
            time.sleep(1)
            out = str(itemsTextList)
            self.textBrowser.setText(out)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

    def Stop(self):
        global true;
        true = 0;
        print "Stop"
        widget = QWidget()
        QMessageBox.warning(widget, "Welcome", "Data Transfer Stop")
        # sys.exit()


    def close(self, event):
        #global DD
        widget = QWidget()
        message = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(widget, "Quit", "Do you really want to quit?",
                                             QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if message == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print "exit"
            self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
            self.ui = Login.Ui_Login()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
            #DD.hide()
            DD.close()


        else:
            print "Continue"
            global true;
            true = 1;

        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 460, 131, 41))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("image: url(:/newPrefix/index.jpeg);"))
        self.label_7.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.label_7.mousePressEvent = self.close
```

Comment: im new in python please help me.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the error and why you guess it fails? Anyways I think it could be if the secondary window is by any way sustained by main object. But no idea.

Comment: the error is                                                                                             Correct credentials!
exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jai-bholenath/Downloads/withBlueshade/DD.py", line 73, in close
    DD.close()
NameError: global name 'DD' is not defined

Comment: login done and move to second window and close login window properly. But if logout second window that is not close. i know there is stupid some logic but i can't understand this..

Comment: Is because you are doing DD.close() but that only has sense when you imported DD from main object. You close something that does not exist in the context. Just find the way to close itself. I don't know python but something like self.window.close() ? Then launch main program again.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greensystem/PycharmProjects/testing/DD.py", line 81, in exit
    self.DD.close()
AttributeError: 'Ui_DD' object has no attribute 'DD'

Comment: if i am closing the DD object with self. the Attribute error show

Comment: Any suggestion for me?

Comment: When you expect some reply, you should also give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyone who executes the code you have put here gets only one error: `ImportError: No module named LoginError`

Answer (score 0):

I can see two main issues with your program.

Firstly, why do the two Ui's depend on each other? You've done `import DD` in Login.py and `import Login` in DD.py This makes no sense to me. What you should do, is have a third file, say, `Main.py` and import both Login and DD into it. Then you can easily jump around from one window to another.

Secondly, in DD.py, there is not **object** called `DD`. Your class is called `Ui_DD` which lives in DD.py. So if you call `DD.close()` what should python think `DD` is? Thus the complaint `NameError`.

A simple anology: Consider a company named "XYZ Inc." and an employee called "Mr. P". You are trying to get rid of "Mr. P" by saying "XYZ Inc., get out!" which makes no sense. In your case DD.py is "XYZ Inc", and "Ui_DD" is "Mr. P".

Comment: thanks Mr. Marcus. i will try your concept and reply soon. thanks again

Comment: i create new file that is main.py and call both files in main files.

Comment: So now you can put the login and the other widget in a loop, so to speak.

Comment: Great. I'd suggest you put up a simple code which shows how it solves your problem and accept it. This way you and the site both grow... :)